# Remember me in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

When I use

```
Auth::attempt();
```

method to authenticate user I also put some user data in session, like user id, role, etc. And I put the session lifetime to zero. So, when user checks the "remember me" chechbox laravel remembers him even after he closed the browser. However, when he closes the browser I lost my session data. Although user is logged I don't have anymore some session data associated with him.

I tried this solution:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
if (Auth::check()) {
    $user = Auth::user();

    Session::put('user_id',        $user->id);
    Session::put('company_id',     $user->company_id);
    Session::put('is_super_admin', Company::isSuperAdmin($user->company_id));
    Session::put('is_admin',       $user->is_admin);

    if (Session::get('is_super_admin')) {
        return View::make('admin');
    } else {
        return View::make('client');
    }
} else {
    return View::make('login');
}
});
```

And it works. However, it means that each time the logged user goes to somewhere where I should check if he's logged I must connect to DB, get user data and put it in session, so it's bad solution.

But how can I remember my own user session details even after the browser is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use remember me in Laravel you should add an extra true boolean flag as an argument in `Auth::attempt()`. See the documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password), true))
{
    // The user is being remembered...
}
```

Edit:
Don't put your data in the session yourself. To Access that data use `Auth::user()->field`.

Comment: I know about the "true" flag and it works. But I don't want to access user data by Auth::user()->field because for each url I would connect to DB and get data from DB. Previously I used sessions to keep data which is often required, like user_role. And in what case I'll use sessions after all

Comment: What is the problem with getting the data from the database? I would recommend not to optimize before you actually run into performance issues (which is very unlikely for a simple get query).

Comment: Well, okay, thanks for advice, I'll retrive data from DB then

Comment: Hey, I had a project that syncing between forum with the laravel. So I need some session to hold some important information and I dont want the laravel session expired when the forum is NOT. The problem is, how to make the session unexpired? Thanks.